# Python: Sorting a two files based on the order of one

Tags: python

I've been trying to do this task all day, and I really want to learn how to do it using Python. I want to take two tab-delimited files, one with an ID only and the other with the same ID and some description. I can easily merge these files on the shared ID field with unix join, but for that I need to sort both and I want to keep the ordering of the first file.

Ive tried some code below, and my method has been to try and add things to a tuple, as from my understanding, they will keep their order as you add to it. I havent been able to get anything to work though. Can anyone help?

Sample files:

```
file1 ->
111889
1437390
123
27998
2525778
12
1345

file2 ->
2525778'\t'item778
1345'\t'item110
123'\t'item1000
12'\t'item8889
111889'\t'item1111
1437390'\t'item222
27998'\t'item12

output ->
111889'\t'item1111
1437390'\t'item222
123'\t'item1000
27998'\t'item12
2525778'\t'item778
12'\t'item8889
1345'\t'item110
```

This what I have so far:

```
import sys

add_list = ()

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as file1, open(sys.argv[2], 'rb') as file2:
        for line2 in file2:
                f1, f2, f3 = line2.split('\t')
                #print f1, f2, f3
                for row in file1:
                        #print row
                        if row != f1:
                                break
                        else:
                                add_list.append(f1,f2,'\n')
                                break
```

Comment: How big do you expect your files to be? Can we assume that they can all be read into memory at the same time? If not then it will require more complicated out-of-core methods...

Comment: a tuple is immutable (can't be changed), and you can't append to it. You want to use a list, `[]`.  Also, `.append()` only accepts a single item.

Comment: Indeed, your algorithmical complexity is O(n^2), that means, for an input set of n items, it processes all items n^2 times. The merging, especially if it can be done in memory is of O(n) complexity (using the dictionary approach). For 1000 items it means it is 3 orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use Python *dictionaries*, they are perfect for this task…

Here is a complete answer:

```
import sys

# Each id is mapped to its item name
# (split() splits at whitespaces (including tabulation and newline), with no empty output strings):
items = dict(line.split() for line in open(sys.argv[2]))  # Inspired by mgilson's answer

with open(sys.argv[1]) as ids:
    for line in ids:
        id = line.rstrip()  # newline removed
        print '{}\t{}'.format(id, items[id])
```

Here is the result:

```
% python out.py file1.txt file2.txt
111889  item1111
1437390 item222
123     item1000
27998   item12
2525778 item778
12      item8889
1345    item110
```

PS: Note that I did not open the files in `rb` mode, as there is no need to keep the original newline bytes, here, since we get rid of trailing newlines.

Comment: Thats great thanks. For some reason I was thinking that dictionaries would still leave me without the function of sorting against the first file

Comment: Dictionaries indeed don't have a defined order. However, for the output, the ids are taken from your `file1` one by one: this is where the ordering comes from. The dictionary is only used for associating an id to an item.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dictionary which maps the ID to the field value from the second file:

```
with open('file2') as fin:
   d = dict(x.split(None, 1) for x in fin)
```

Then I would use the first file to construct the output in order from the dictionary:

```
with open('file1') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        key = line.strip()
        fout.write('{key}\t{value}\n'.format(key=key, value=d[key])
```

Comment: Good dictionary creation! `strip()` would be better as `rstrip()`, as this is more robust (not fully needed here, however) but more importantly more explicit (newline stripping). On the other hand, limiting the number of splits in `split()` is not really necessary, as the input file has two columns, and if it does not, then items have tabs, which should not play well with the tabbed output anyway…

Comment: @EOL -- Yeah.  The best option here really depends on the constraints on the text in the file.  I think that I'm going to make the assumption that whitespace other than newline isn't significant at all.  If that's true, I think `x.split(None, 1)` combined with `line.strip` is best, but it could be that explicitly splitting on `\t` is better if the id can have spaces in it... That would be a funny id though.

Comment: Yeah, that's a reasonable choice. Just to nitpick: I would argue that it is better to write for the regular case than for exceptional ones, so as to implicitly document what the code really wants to do (here: removing newline instead of handling in addition the possibility that the input was corrupted with leading whitespaces), so I would really use `rstrip()`. I understand your point, though. :)

Comment: Also: `fout.write(…)` with a string that ends with `\n` is better as `print >> fout,…`, since it is immediately explicit that you print a line ending with newline, and since it automatically produces a platform-dependent newline. On Windows, I don't expect the `write()` approach to work (missing `\r` characters).

Comment: @EOL, if you're writing with universal newlines, then `'\n'` will correctly be written as `\r\n` on windows as long as you're in text mode (I believe -- I haven't used a windows computer for a LONG time, so I could be wrong about that...).  e.g. you open with mode = `'w'` and not `'wb'`.  personally, I feel that `f.write('...\n')` is *more* explicit with the newline appending than `print >>stream, ...`.  FWIW, I've always disliked the `print >> stream, stuff` form of the print statement.  It doesn't feel like python syntax to me.

Comment: Humm, you're right, you're in text mode, with the `w` mode, so I agree, this probably works on Windows. As for the `>>` syntax, I agree. I'm glad that Python 3 has `print(…, file=…)` instead—which by the way encourages us to *not* end the printed string explicitly with `\n`. I would even add that putting explicitly a `\n` is a little confusing because it might become a `\r\n`, whereas there no confusion is possible with `print`. :)

Comment: PS: And to nitpick again: "writing with universal newlines" is not fully technically correct, in Python: only *reading* can be called "universal" (the universal `U` mode is for reading only). The relevant phrasing here is really "writing to a text file", which writes with the *local* (not universal, obviously), platform-dependent newlines. I just want to get the concept straights for readers of these comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
out = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as file1, open(sys.argv[2], 'rb') as file2:
    d2 = {}
    for line in file2:
        (key, val) = line.split('\t')
        d2[key] = val
    lines = file1.readlines()
    out = { x:d2[x] for x in lines }
```

I am not sure about your sorting basis.